# помогите, пожалуйста, шифрую строку методом Цезаря, но почему-то не работает

Tags: ассемблер

```
__asm {
            mov ecx, _size; _size - размер сроки
            mov ebx, s; s - строка
            mov edx, _key; _key - величина сдвига
            lebel : mov eax, [ebx]
                    add eax, edx
                    cmp eax, 7Ah;
                   ja metka
                   mov [ebx] , eax
                   add ebx , 4
                   metka: mov edx , eax
                          sub edx , 7Ah
                          mov eax , 61h
                          add eax , edx
                          mov [ebx] , eax
                          add ebx , 4
            loop lebel
        }

__asm {  //исправленный вариант
    mov ecx, _size
    mov ebx, offset s
    lebel : mov al, byte ptr [ebx]
            add al,byte ptr [_key]
            cmp al, 122;
            ja metka
            mov byte ptr [ebx], al
                inc ebx
                loop lebel
                metka : mov  byte ptr[_key], al
                sub  byte ptr[_key], 122
                mov al, 97
                add al, byte ptr[_key]
                mov byte ptr[ebx], al
                inc ebx
                loop lebel

}
```

//шифрую в английском алфавите

Comment: `mov eax, [ebx]` EAX - четырехбайтный регистр, поэтому в него сразу загружается 4 байта из строки. что бы 4х байтное значение было сравнимо с 7A, у него 3 старших байта должны быть нули. я сильно сомневаюсь, что у вас в строке значащие байты идут на каждой 4й позиции, а все остальное заполнено нулями. Так что вам надо практически во всем алгоритме использовать однобайтные операции, например с регистром AL

Comment: @Mike, почему не ответом?

Comment: @Mike, я исправила, но снова не работает исправно, если вам не сложно, то посмотрите, пожалуйста